# Reporting tool for Performance Monitor

Tags: windows, perfmon

I am looking for an application I can use to consume performance monitor logs and report on them.  Is there an application you have good success with to display the metrics you have captured with PerfMon and point out problem areas etc.?

Thank you,

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will point you to [a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108/perfmon-file-analysis-tools/27130#27130) on StackOverflow, regarding a very similar question.

Comment: I've heard from a SQL Server DBA doing just that - using LogParser to pull Perfmon data into a database and report on 'em that way.

Answer (score 1):

PAL is very good.  To use it:

Create a set of perfmon counters for each type of server (Web, SQL, App, etc...) you wish to monitor, customized to that specific server role. Export the counters as an HTML file, and import it on each server. Then run perfmon based on this file for several hours or days to capture a realistic workload on the server(s).

Then feed those raw logs to PAL, and it will provide a nice summary "traffic light" style report notifying you of problem areas.

Comment: A stumbling block I have hit using PAL is creating my own templates to be reported on.  For instance, the web server template is for .NET applications and I have the need for asp, different counters are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Performance Analysis of Logs (PAL) Tool](http://pal.codeplex.com/) on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com), it certainly seems to have potential.  Anyone use this tool?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Operations Manager has no trouble doing this if it's just reporting on problem areas you're after (with built-in thresholds by the people who built Windows) - any decent (windows-aware) monitoring suite would be able to do that actually... but if you're after more intrinsic manual analysis Microsofts Logparser should be able to feed the data into an easily queryable format and then go from there.

I'd try that PAL, it looks interesting enough. I'd normally not be interested in digging through reports by myself though - I want my monitoring system to do it for me and preferably fix the problems as well... perhaps feeding it the reports from PAL would be useful if it doesn't do that type of monitoring to begin with...? Depends on the granularity of the reports I guess, interesting question.